# How can I use gh3 in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use this project https://github.com/k33g/gh3 in my Angular / Typescript project however this does not have `npm install`

How would I use it in my Angular project so that I can write the regular syntax

```
import {foo} from 'lib'
```

Do I have to create some special file for it? If so, how would I do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about importing its js files in index.html?

Comment: Check the stories on the cli github

Comment: @dasfdsa: Angular cli seed project will give errors because when I use the library without importing it say it cannot find that.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof: Sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: There is a stories page on the cli gihub that explains how to use libraries.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof: Could you please share it's link?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories you could have googled that yourself.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof: Yes I could have only if I understood what you meant. Thank you for the link. I will explore it.